# django logging handler

Tags: django, logging, handlers

How can I get the logging handler object instance(s) in django (>=1.3)? with standard python logging I instantiate the logger and then the handler:

```
h = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler( FILE, 'D', 1)
```

I want `h` or the array of `h`'s that django uses when i use its' `LOGGING` dict in `settings.py`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to get all active handlers by:

```
import logging
h = []
for a in logging.root.handlers:
    h.append( a.stream )
```

(in the above i wanted to the file objects rather than the actual handlers themselves)

hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is old, but still useful. Thank you. However, looping is unnecessary. Use `from copy import deepcopy; h = deepcopy(logging.root.handlers)` instead.